# seconds to minute:seconds from mysql to smarty

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I have this query

```
$result = select_query("tblemails", "", array("userid" => $userid), "id", "DESC", "0,5");
$lastfivemail = array();
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$lastfivemail[] = array("id" => $data["id"], "processtime" => $data["processtime"], "date" => frommysqldate($data["date"], "time"), "subject" => $data["subject"] ? $data["subject"] : "No Subject");
continue;
}
$templatevars["lastfivemail"] = $lastfivemail;
```

and this

```
"processtime" => $data["processtime"]
```

brings the time it took to send the email in seconds.

I need to show it in a minute:second format.

here is the smarty side

```
<div class="clientssummarybox">
<div class="title">{$_ADMINLANG.clientsummary.emailsheading}</div>
<table class="clientssummarystats" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
{foreach key=num from=$lastfivemail item=email}
<tr class="{cycle values=",altrow"}"><td align="center">{$email.date} - <a href="#" onClick="window.open('clientsemails.php?&displaymessage=true&id={$email.id}','','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return false">{$email.subject}</a></td><td>{$email.processtime}</td></tr>
{foreachelse}
<tr><td align="center">{$_ADMINLANG.clientsummary.noemails}</td></tr>
{/foreach}
</table>
</div>

</td><td width="25%" valign="top">
```

thanks

Comment: do it in php via date() function, and just use the assigned variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant but:

```
$t = $data["processtime"];

$mins = floor($t/60); 
$secs = $t%60; 
$data["processtime"] = sprintf("%02d:%02d",$mins,$secs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Smarty 2 and up you can use

`{$email.processtime|date_format:'%H:%M:%S'}`

[**See reference here**](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.date.format.tpl)

Answer (score 0):

I used a "smarty-only" solution recently to solve the problem of converting seconds to more readable H:M:S format. Assuming you have a variable `$seconds`

```
{assign var='duration' value='%02d:%02d:%02d'}
Duration: {$seconds|sprintf:floor($seconds/3600):(($seconds/60)%60):$seconds}
```